# Cannot get cross domain socket.io example to work

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm having a lot of trouble getting a simple cross-domain example to work with socket.io. I have a node server set up on heroku and just want to connect to it from a client running on my own computer. Everything that I can find claims that I can load it in the following manner:

In index.html:

And in client.js
  socket = io.connect('http://www.mysitehere.org:5000');

However, every time I try this I get the following error:

GET http://www.mysitehere.org:5000/socket.io/1/?t=1398190283942 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And I see nothing in my heroku logs to indicate that it even saw a connection attempt. Can anyone help explain what's going on? Or at least point me in a direction where I can get more information?

Comment: Is the node server running? Do you have a firewall blocking port 5000?

Comment: Yeah, the server is running and everything works fine when I run the client on the server itself. The problem is only occurring when I run the client from anywhere else.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am experiencing the same issue currently.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku port is assigned dynamically. You should read it from process.env.PORT and launch your node app using that port.